# How to add an Icon left of text inside container

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following below widget:

```
Widget get _animatedButtonUI => Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 290,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Color(0xFF9EC33B),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'COTINUE WITH GOOGLE',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xFF9EC33B),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

as it was looks like the below figure:

[image]

Now I need to add Icon left of the `Text` as the below image:

[image]

So how can I do this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to insert a Row inside the Container, just like this:

```
Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 290,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Color(0xFF9EC33B),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
         Image.asset(yourImage),
         Center(
          child: Text(
            'COTINUE WITH GOOGLE',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color(0xFF9EC33B),
            ),
          ),
        ),
       ],
      );
```

Edit: Make sure you fix that typo ("COTINUE WITH GOOGLE" => "CONTINUE WITH GOOGLE")